# How to insert user input in a dictionairy - python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, input

I was supposed to insert new items to a dictionary, and the new items would be decided by the user input. I have tried three differents things (the ones marked as comments), but none is working. Does anyone know how to fix it?

```
butikk = {"melk": 14.9, "broed": 24.9, "yoghurt": 12.9, "pizza": 39.9}
print(butikk)

ny_vare = str(input("Skriv inn en matvare og prisen: "))
ny_vare_pris = float(input("Hvor mye koster varen? "))

ny_vare1 = str(input("Skriv inn en matvare: "))
ny_vare1_pris = float(input("Hvor mye koster varen? ")

#butikk.append(ny_vare)
#butikk.append(ny_vare1)

#butikk[ny_vare] = ny_vare_pris
#butikk[ny_vare1] = ny_vare1_pris

#butikk.update(ny_vare : ny_vare_pris)
#butikk.update(ny_vare1 : ny_vare1_pris)

print(butikk)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Would you mind translating the text in the code into English? I'm afraid the majority of us are having trouble understanding the code. Thanks.

Comment: `butikk[ny_vare] = ny_vare_pris` should work.

Comment: i try and the `butikk[ny_vare] = ny_vare_pris` worked.

Comment: You are missing a close parentheses at the right side of `ny_vare1_pris = float(input("Hvor mye koster varen? ")`.  Python (and other compilers) only report a syntax error on the line it is detected, not necessarily the line in error.

Comment: "It's not working" is never a sufficient problem description. A proper [mcve] should include the error message (if any), or explain why the code's output is incorrect and what the expected output would be.

Comment: A side note: There is no need for `str` in `ny_vare = str(input("Skriv inn en matvare og prisen: "))`. The result of `input()` is always a string.

Comment: The `.append` is not for dictionaries. It is for lists and some other classes. One way to check the doc is to look [index for A](https://docs.python.org/3/genindex-A.html) in [Python documentation index](https://docs.python.org/3/genindex.html).

Comment: The [`.update`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) can also be used, only a bit differently. However, for a single key/value pair, it would be too complicated.

Answer (score -1):

Okay, so your problem is solved. To be noted, you had done 2 things wrong here.

> *First*, you **missed a bracket** on `line 8` and
>
> *Second* one is that you should apply `{}`  to update the dictionary.

Let me show you the correct code:

```
butikk = {
    "melk": 14.9,
    "broed": 24.9,
    "yoghurt": 12.9,
    "pizza": 39.9
}

ny_vare = input("Skriv inn en matvare og prisen: ")
ny_vare_pris = float(input("Hvor mye koster varen? "))
ny_vare1 = input("Skriv inn en matvare: ")
ny_vare1_pris = float(input("Hvor mye koster varen? "))

butikk.update({ny_vare: ny_vare_pris})
butikk.update({ny_vare1: ny_vare1_pris})

print(butikk)
```

Now you will get your desired output.